# running a function with a timer in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I want to run a function after the app enters background, which will launch a local notification, what I did was the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0f target:self selector:@selector(triggerLocalNotification) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }];

   }
```

it works only if the iPhone is connected to the MacBook, if we disconnect it and run the app, this function isn't been called.
Any help?

Comment: you can schedule a LocalNotification when appResignsActive with the time that is 30 second from current time.

Comment: it worked, but it gives only 2 or three notifications, then it stops.

Comment: You can schedule a repeating notification. You can't run a timer in the background.

Comment: and how do I schedule a repeating notification?